# "type" command in python gives unexpected results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I ran the following code in the Python interpreter:

```
>>> s
<sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session object at 0x7f4fc8d69e10>
>>> type(s)
<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>
>>> type(s) == sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session
False
```

(1) Why does the interpreter say the type of `s` is not `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`, when it just said that it was?

(2) If the `type` command doesn't work, what is the best way to tell if an object is a `Session` object?  (I'm trying to use this in an assertion to validate the input to a function)

(3) Just for fun, I tried to do this with a primitive type, and it worked.  Why are integers different here?

```
>>> type(3)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(3) == int
True
```

Comment: It works  for me. `s = orm.session.Session();type(s) == sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session -> True`, what does  `isinstance(s, sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session)` output?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It returns True

Comment: You would be better off using isinstance anyway. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/differences-between-isinstance-and-type-in-python

Comment: Did you `reload` any modules or do anything that might cause modules to be reloaded?

Comment: What does `type(s).__mro__` show?

Comment: @user2357112 >>> type(s).__mro__
(<class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>, <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'>, <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session._SessionClassMethods'>, <type 'object'>)

Comment: Aside: `type` is a function, not a command, in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `s` is actually an instance of a subclass of `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`. The subclass is confusingly also named `sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session`.

Looking at the SQLAlchemy source, it seems likely that this object was produced by a `sqlalchemy.orm.session.sessionmaker`, which [creates a subclass](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py#L2730) of `Session` for reasons I'm not entirely clear on. I don't know if this behavior is documented; I didn't find any mention of it in the docs on a quick look.